# Dictionary of generic functions with different type per entry

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Is it possible to achieve having typed `func` in a dict, with different types as keys and no casting in the `func`.

Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var funcDict = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object, bool>>()
        {
            {typeof(Person), (Person p1, Person p2) => p1.Id == p2.Id},
            {typeof(Dog), (Dog d1, Dog d2) => d1.Name == d2.Name},
        };

        var p1 = new Person()
        {
            Id = 4
        };

        var p2 = new Person();

        Console.WriteLine(funcDict[p1.GetType()].Invoke(p1, p2));
    }
}
```

Best I can come up with is creating the funcs with `object` types and then casting in the `func` body, but if possible would like to avoid that, cause it would make for a much cleaner API.

```
var funcDict = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object, bool>>()
{
    {typeof(Person), (o1, o2) => ((Person) o1).Id == ((Person) o2).Id},
};
```

Comment: Could you not use a shared interface for Person and Dog and then get them to implement an "Equals" method? Then it won't matter what object it is because their "Equals" functionality will be separated into each class. You could try using IComparable for this.

Comment: No, I'm building a library that I'd like to be usable without models depending on some interface, and the same Type should be able to be comparable differently if the config changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer would be no, not unless you use dynamic typing. But you could hide the ugliness:

```
public class FunctionDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> dict = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    public void Add<T>(Func<T, T, bool> method) => dict.Add(typeof(T), method);
    public bool Run<T>(T a, T b) => ((Func<T, T, bool>)dict[typeof(T)]).Invoke(a, b);
}
```

disclaimer: No error handling, not tested.

You could replace "object" with "dynamic" in the example above to get rid of the cast. But I would probably not, since it would probably be a bit slower, and not much easier to read.